# Rails 3 ORDER BY FIELD and last

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-order-by, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hello I have an issue with Rails 3.2 and ordering.

When wanting to order a collection by a field, when calling `.last` `ActiveRecord` behaves weirdly...

```
   >> User.order("FIELD(id, '1')")
   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY FIELD(id, '1')
   => []
   >> User.order("FIELD(id, '1')").first
   User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY FIELD(id, '1') LIMIT 1
   => nil
   >> User.order("FIELD(id, '1')").last
   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY FIELD(id DESC, '1') DESC LIMIT 1
   Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

As you can see calling last on the relation add `DESC` twice, but it should have only put it after the whole `ORDER BY FIELD`, and not inside the parenthesis..

Do anyone has an idea how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `FIELD` function is not supported by the ActiveRecord `order` method.  Using the order method will parse out commas as field separators and append `DESC` to each segment when you invoke `last`.

As an alternative you can either avoid using FIELD(), or avoid using `last` and just provide forward and reverse scopes

```
scope :forward_order, order("FIELD(id, '1') ASC")
scope :reverse_order, order("FIELD(id, '1') DESC")
```

Then you can use `User.reverse_order.first` in place of `User.order(...).last`

Comment: Yeah, sometimes ActiveRecord cannot "reverse" your `ORDER` directive and you have to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is old but I run into this problem today and found a workaround that doesn't require the use of extra scopes.

Create a SQL function to wrap the call to `FIELD`, this way there will be no comma in the invocation to `order`. This is PostgreSQL but the translation is straightforward:

```
CREATE FUNCTION field1(value text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN FIELD(value, 1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE
```

Calling `last` in ActiveRecord now works:

```
User.order('field1(id)').last
```