# Want to query in array and get result of ids that been passed into query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made a query which returns me array of ids. like below :

```
PsychographicsAnswer.group('psychographics_question_id')
                    .order('count(*) DESC')
                    .limit(5)
                    .pluck(:psychographics_question_id)
```

this return me following result

```
[175, 174, 176, 173, 172]
```

Now i want to find question with same ids and exactly in same order. I am querying in following way.

```
PsychographicsQuestion.where(:id=>PsychographicsAnswer
                        .group('psychographics_question_id')
                        .order('count(*) DESC')
                        .limit(5)
                        .pluck(:psychographics_question_id))
                      .pluck(:id)
```

this return me following result:

```
[172, 173, 174, 175, 176]
```

As you can see ids not in order like i pass in query. I want to get result exactly in same fashion as i querying in.

Comment: I think you may be looking for mysql function FIELD, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096948/rails-3-order-by-field-and-last

Comment: @hassan your problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Answer_ids = PsychographicsAnswer
                    .group('psychographics_question_id')
                    .order('count(*) DESC')
                    .limit(5)
                    .pluck(:psychographics_question_id) // Answers_id => [175, 174, 176, 173, 172]

PsychographicsQuestion.unscoped.where(:id=>Answer_ids)
                  .order("FIELD(id, #{Answer_ids.join(',')})")
                  .pluck(:id) // [175, 174, 176, 173, 172]
```

I think you may be looking for mysql function FIELD.

Comment: I'm not sure this will change anything, as the database just returns matching object in the order it find them

Comment: I edited my answer, i tried with a similar structure, it works and i hope it will be useful for you later may be ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order questions according to number of its associated answers then I think you can do like this

```
Question
  .joins(:answers)
  .select("users.*, count(annswers.id) as scount")
  .group("questions.id")
  .order("scount DESC")
```

Comment: I found solution by customizing ur idea and it works thanks.
By following query i solved my issue.

`PsychographicsQuestion.joins(:psychographics_answers)
 .select("psychographics_questions.* , count(psychographics_answers.psychographics_question_id) as scount")
 .group("psychographics_questions.id") 
 .order("scount DESC")`